# (iphone) how to set 'atomic' @property for a variable?

Tags: iphone, properties, atomic

I want to use an integer variable from multiple threads.
Hence I want to make getter/setter atomic operation.

at header file

```
@property (retain) NSNumber* myNumber;
```

at implementation file

```
@synthesize myNumber;
```

won't compile, what am i missing?
(type of property ‘myNumber’ does not match type of ivar ‘myNumber’)
- edit, I declared it as int myNumber; compilation problem solved

Also, can I use plain int for this? (not NSNumber* )

Comment: What is your `myNumber` ivar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you may use `int` instead of `NSNumber`. Type choice depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

The particular error message you get says that your instance variable has a different type than the property with the same name. Do you clare your ivar as `int myNumber`? In this case you should write

```
@property int myNumber;
```

**Update**

Since properties are *atomic* by default, you do not need to explicitly write:

```
@property (atomic) int myNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. > @property (assign) int myNumber;
2. Add in @interface `NSNumber *myNumber;`

Comment: would int have "atomic" property?

Comment: @Eugene: If you don't specify a property's atomicity it is always `atomic` by default, whether it's a primitive type or pointer type.

Comment: Yes the @propery is implicit atomic.

Comment: I want to say that the default behavior of the property is atomic.

Answer (score 1):

Check your instance variable type.

Something like this in your header file:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    NSNumber *myNumber;
}
@property (retain) NSNumber *myNumber;
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this,

```
@property (atomic , retain) NSNumber* myNumber;
```

Or use this[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588866/objective-c-properties-atomic-vs-nonatomic) it may be helpful

Comment: There is no "atomic" in properties, is there? Properties are atomic by default.